# SQL Server query with null value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, null

In my C# code, I have to do an SQL Query like this :

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field0 = {0} AND 
    Field1 = {1}", field0, field1)
```

When field1 = null in c# and NULL in database this query doesn't work. (I have to use a different syntax with IS NULL)

How can I correct this without make an if (in reality, I have 10 fields...) ?

Comment: Looks ripe for SQL Injection. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Oded: `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` is *not* the same as `string.Format`, despite the similarity in syntax. `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` parameterizes the query automatically.

Comment: @Adam Robinson - Thanks for the info. I will leave my earlier comment there, so your information will be in context :)

Comment: so many things wrong... so little time....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, SQL server does not allow you to compare a value to `null`. All comparisons resolve to `false`, even those that are logically opposite. In other words, you can do:

`where field = 1` and `where field <> 1`. If `field` is null, both logically resolve to false.

In any case, you need an explicit check for `null` in your query:

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery(@"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 
    (Field0 = {0} or (Field0 is null and {0} is null))  AND 
    (Field1 = {1} or (Field1 is null and {0} is null))", field0, field1)
```

Comment: ` AND [_TYPE] = CASE WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN [_TYPE] ELSE @TYPE END` this runs fine in SQL Server 2008 and it's quite driving me mad, as it can't be used in C# SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the short variant of the if statement.
I don't think you can handle your problem without an if statement.
Example:

```
String.Format("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field0 {0} ", value==null ? "IS NULL" : String.Format("= {0}", value))
```

It is also possible to parameterize the query by using "@ParameterName"

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<ProductionUnit>(
  String.Format("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field0 {0} @Parameter1",
  value==null ? "IS", "="), new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", value));
```

Regards

Comment: Interestign approach. {1} could still be parameterised of course

Comment: You will have NullReferenceException because String.Format will call value.ToString even if first condition will return true.

Comment: @cement: You can pass `null` to `string.Format`, though this design won't work in this particular scenario. `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` (which is what the user is using) is not just a string formatting function, as it automatically parameterizes the query using the supplied values. This approach will not product valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string appendCondition(String sqlQuery, String field, Object value)
{ 
 string resultQuery = sqlQuery + " " + value == null ? " IS NULL " : "=" + value.ToString();
 return resultQuery;
}
```

Hope you can add simple logic to add "WHERE" or "AND" by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

well, the first thing i would do is remove the select *.  BAD!

the second thing i would do is make this a stored procedure.

```
    create procedure dbo.MyTableSelect
    @field0 int,
    @field1 int=null
as
begin

    select
        *
    from MyTable
    where Field0=@field0
        and (@field1 is null or Field1=@field1)



end
```

you then can change your code to this

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery("exec dbo.MyTableSelect @field0={0}, @field1 = {1}", field0, field1)
```